# geom_density doesn't fill correctly with scale_y_log10

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

Code:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(0)
xvar <- rnorm(100)
ggplot(data.frame(xvar), aes(xvar)) + geom_density(fill="lightblue") + scale_y_log10()
```

The graph is something like this:
[image: badgraph]

How can I make the graph shade on the right side of (viz. below) the density estimate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `stat_density` by default fills between the density and the `y=0` line of the *transformed* data.  So transformations that alter the y=0 line will fall victim to problems of this sort.  I personally think this is a bug in `ggplot2`, although since graphical grammar experts probably argue that y-transformed densities are meaningless, the bug may not get a lot of attention.

A very kludgy workaround is to manually add an offset to `..density..`, which you will have to explicitly invoke, and then change the breaks to make it look like you didn't do anything weird.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
set.seed(0)
xvar <- rnorm(100000)
quartz(height=4,width=6)
ggplot(data.frame(xvar), aes(x=xvar, y=log10(..density..)+4)) + 
    geom_density(fill='lightblue') +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4), 
        labels=c('0.0001', '0.001', '0.01', '0.1','1'), limits=c(0,4),
        name='density')
quartz.save('![StackOverflow_29111741_v2][1].png')
```

That code produces this graph:
[image: Kludged graph]

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a `ggplot2` or even an `R` issue but is simply an issue with the tails of a probability distribution being undersampled for your sample sizes.  The log axis can go down forever, taking infinitely long to "reach" zero, but no finite sample size can ever hope to cover the increasingly improbable regions of the distribution.

So, to make the plot pretty, you need to both (a) increase the number of points from 100 to 10,000 or higher, while (b) keeping the plot `ylim`s the same.  (Otherwise the extra data you draw in your `rnorm` call will *sparsely* populate the tails of the gaussian even farther away from the mean, convincing `ggplot2` to make automatic `y` axis limits even lower, in the range of the poorly-sampled tails, and the noisiness that you don't like will return.)

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
set.seed(0)
xvar <- rnorm(100000)
ggplot(data.frame(xvar), aes(xvar)) + 
    geom_density(fill="lightblue") + 
    scale_y_continuous(trans=log10_trans(), limits = c(0.01, 1))
```

This generates this plot, which I think is what you want. 
[image]

Comment: Wait, I just figure out that you probably meant something else by your question...I'll try to come up with another answer.  Sorry if I misunderstood you.

Comment: That is, you want the parabola to be colored, not the rectangle behind the parabola...right?