# Incorrect color filling of overlaid histograms with log-y scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay two histograms and plot their y-axis in log scale. Some example code:

```
dat1<- data.frame(
  x = rpois(1000, 50),
  y = rep("X1", 1000)
)

dat2<- data.frame(
  x = rpois(1000, 30),
  y = rep("X0", 1000)
)

dat<- rbind(dat1, dat2)

p <-   ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, fill = y)) +
       geom_histogram(
           aes(y=..density..), 
           breaks= seq( min(dat$x), max(dat$x),(max(dat$x)-min(dat$x))/30 ), 
           alpha=0.4, 
           position="identity", lwd=0.2
       ) + 
       scale_y_log10() +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black"), labels=c("X1", "X0"))
print(p)
```

Without setting `scale_y_log10()`, I got something like this:

[image]

However, after using `scale_y_log10()`, the histogram colors are not filled correctly (see below, the overlap of two histograms is not filled with colors, instead, the empty area is filled). Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=x, y=log10(..density.. + 1), fill=y), alpha=0.4, position="identity", lwd=0.2) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black"), labels=c("X1", "X0"))
```

you get:
[image]

Some explanation: now you have `x` values in your plot with a count of zero. This gives some problems when doing a log-transformation. By adding `1`, you are able to include zero's in a log-scale.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this nice explanation! Is there a way to have a transformation with 10 as the base just like scale_y_log10()?

Comment: The `log1p` transformation is basically a `log10(x+1)` transformation. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmm, from the plot output you generated it seems like log1p still does not transform like log10 though. I think a correct log10 plot would look very similar to my second plot except the color

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 I've added an explanation.

Comment: Hi, I suspect the log1p's base is e. A simple test: log1p(10) produces 2.397895. If log1p is 10 based, the output should be close to 1.

Comment: @xiaoxiao87 You're right. Luckily, the solution is quite simple. See my updated answer.

Comment: This question is nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111741/geom-density-doesnt-fill-correctly-with-scale-y-log10

Comment: Hi Jaap, thanks for your solution. Yes this could be a workaround. However, by adding 1 vertical shift to a density distribution will significantly change the "shape" of the distribution. Well, you may argue that taking a log10 also changes the shape of the density distribution - it is a transformation anyway. But in many cases it is much easier to interpret a log10 transformation on density than density shifted by 1. Not sure I made myself clear..

Comment: If you look at the question and answer I linked to, you don't have to do the shift inside the `log10()`.  I.e. you can transform and then shift, instead of shifting then transforming.  That preserves data shape.

Comment: @CurtF. If you have zero values, you have to shift inside the `log10`. Else you will get the same result the OP got initially. In this case, shifting inside the `log10` preserves the data shape much better than shifting outside as in the question you linked to.

Comment: "Shifting" inside the `log10` is best viewed as not a shift, but a completely new type of data transformation that is unrelated to log transformation.  The original data can't be recovered by exponentiation of the transformed data without knowledge of the "shift" parameter.  That isn't true for an addition outside of the `log`.  Addition _to_ a `log` is the same as multiplying the original data.